# Primes dividing Integers

Tags: probability, prime-numbers

I randomly choose two integers. What is the probability that a certain prime number *p* does not divide both integers? Express your answer in terms of *p*.

Comment: "Randomly choosing an integer" is not a well-defined thing.

Comment: There are an infinite amount of integers.....

Comment: To be precise, there are lots of ways of choosing integers randomly, there are even some such that every integer has nonzero probability, but there is no way of doing it so that every integer has *equal* probability.

Comment: Also, it's not clear whether "$p$ does not divide both integers" means (not($p|x$ and $p|y$)) or ((not $p|x$) and (not $p|y$)).

Answer (score 1):

The naive answer is that the two integers will be *large* so the probability that $p$ divides each is $\frac {1}p$.  In this spirit the divisibility of $p$ into each is independent, so the chance it divides neither one is ???  Others will complain (correctly) that there is no uniform probability distribution on the integers, but I think this is the spirit of the question.

Comment: If an integer $x$ is chosen at random in a large interval (compared to $p$), the probability that $p$ divides $x$ is closer to $1/p$ than $(p-1)/p$. You probably have a typo here.

Comment: @minar:  you are right.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The limit density of such independently-chosen pairs is $1-\frac{1}{p^2}$.  The probability that a random integer is divisible by $p$ is $\frac{1}{p}$, but since we are trying to exclude *two* such numbers, square that, and to exclude them rather than include them, take the complement.  $p$ doesn't even have to be prime.